# Registry key context menu

Tags: c++

I'm working in C\C++. When I right click on a registry key it gives me the options such as "Expand, Rename, Export" How can I add "Take Ownership" to a registry key's right click context menu? I have found how to do this for files and folders, but a registry key lacks a file type extension.  Maybe a context menu handler although those also seem to expect a file type?. This works but
not for registry keys.

```
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\takeownership]
    @="Take ownership"
    "HasLUAShield"=""
    "NoWorkingDirectory"=""

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\takeownership\command]
    @="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant     administrators:F"
    "IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's unclear what you're asking, and you haven't provided a [mcve] to show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Windows Explorer, the standard Windows Registry Editor does not support user-defined context menu extensions.  What you are asking for is simply not possible without resorting to low-level hooks or creating your own editor.